# Angular 2 route restriction with AngularFire 2 Auth

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm trying to restrict routes to be available only to authenticated users. So far I've added a service call in every route component constructor to check if the user is logged. If not, you get redirected to the login route(index):

```
logCheck(){
  this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
    if(!user){
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
});
```

It works. But I'm not sure if using the constructor of each route component for this is the correct way of doing things, because you are actually loading the component before being kicked out.
Is there a better way to do it? Like using additional params in the app.routes const maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Guard, that follows the same logic but is instead used with the router, so that when someone tries to access a route, if the service boolean is not set to true, then you get redirected.

Check-out this part of the angular.io router documentation : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

There are examples on how to do it, but with what you have already done it should be pretty fast.

Comment: Did you find a working solution using guards ? If so, please do not forget to validate answers. Thanks