# Angular2: After authorization routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an admin panel, I'm using a router for moving to pages. The admin panel will consist of the sidebar(Component), header(Component) and content(Component). In content i put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. When I use LoginComponent for autorization in the page shows sidebar and header, because `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside content. I use directive *ngIf for visibility sidebar(Component), header(Component) but it is not best practise in my opinion. Can I do it with other variant? 
My folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify a bit if possible ? What are you trying to do ? 

If I understood correctly, you are using `*ngIf` to show / hide components if you are not authorized, but you want to do something better than this ?
You should use a router `Guard`. Check out this post's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183404/angular-2-route-restriction-with-angularfire-2-auth/39186038#39186038

Comment: @AlexBeugnet I use a router Guard, but it`s not resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I use "loadChildren" to resolve this problem. This code in app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
       { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
       { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => DashboardModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}, 
       { path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent}
 ]
```

This code in dashboard-routing.module.ts

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
{
 path: '',
 component: DashboardComponent,
 children : [
       { 
         path: '', 
         children:[
                   { path: 'user',  component: UserComponent, canActivate: [DashboardGuard] },
                   { path: 'user-crud',  component: UserCrudComponent, canActivate: [DashboardGuard] },
                   { path: 'user-crud/:id',  component: UserCrudComponent, canActivate: [DashboardGuard] }
                  ]
       },
```

This code in app.component.ts, after autorization, loading dashboard.module and show in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in this component.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
  })

 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(){}
     ngOnInit() {}
 }
```

This code in content.component.ts, all pages show`s in this component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
       selector: 'app-content',
       template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
   })
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() {}
   ngOnInit() {}
}
```